# Schengen short-term visa - Business vs tourism if issuing consulate is different

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, italy, tourist-visas, croatia

[Time sensitive as I have my appointment tomorrow ]

My Schengen trip includes 6 days in Croatia to attend a conference and 8 days in Italy for tourism.

Initially, I applied at the Croatian embassy and they denied processing my application stating that I am staying more days in Italy and directed me to apply at the Italian consulate. I have an appointment at the Italian embassy tomorrow. FYI: My port of entry and exit are Croatia.

**For the Italian embassy appointment, need advice on whether I should add reason as "business" or "tourism" or both in the application?**

Cause, my business need is in Croatia and the Italian embassy mentions that to apply for a business visa, you need a letter from "Italian" company. I have all the required documents, but from Croatian organization

I see 2 options here:

(1) State overall intent as tourism in boh countries and not mention about the conference in Croatia.

(2) Mention about the conference and explain to the officer my situation and show all documents I have. I fear that they might reject stating I do not have documents from Italian company.

Any advice would be very helpful.

I thought (2) is a common situation people face, where their country of longest stay is different from the one of their primary business. If anyone else can share their experience that would be helpful!

Comment: The usual advice on TSE is never to lie to Immigration officials.

Comment: What it is the purpose of the conference? Academic or business conference? Who pay your travel? But also: what do you consider more important? The holidays or the conference? (honestly, we are not your boss)

Answer (score 2):

> (1) State overall intent as tourism in boh countries and not mention about the conference in Croatia.

Do **NEVER** lie to immigration officials. ESPECIALLY to a Schengen official

All Schengen visa applications are stored for 5 years in the Schengen Visa Information System, including all the following data (emphasis mine) :

> The visa authority shall enter the following data in the application file:
>
> [...]
> 4. the following data to be taken from the application form:
>
> > [...]
> >
> > (g) **main destination and duration of the intended stay;**
> >
> > (h) **purpose of travel;**
> >
> > (i) intended date of arrival and departure;
> >
> > (j) intended border of first entry or transit route;
> >
> > [...]

> [*Schengen Visa Information System Article 9.4§g-j*](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32008R0767#d1e897-60-1)

> #### Use of the VIS for examining applications
>
> 1. The competent visa authority shall consult the VIS for the purposes of the examination of applications and the decisions relating
>    to those applications, including the decision whether to annul,
>    revoke, extend or shorten the validity of the visa in accordance with
>    the relevant provisions.
>
> [...]
>
> 3. If the search with one or several of the data listed in paragraph 2 indicates that data on the applicant are recorded in the VIS, the
>    competent visa authority shall be given access to the application
>    file(s) and the **linked application file(s) pursuant to Article 8(3)
>    and (4)**, solely for the purposes referred to in paragraph 1.

> [*Schengen Visa Information System Article 16*](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32008R0767#d1e1419-60-1)

If you suddenly change your purpose, it will get immediately suspicious, and you would risk your visa denied. Which would stain your record for 5 years in Schengen (short-stays only, long-stay visas usually ask for your whole visa history), and likely forever in most other countries

Comment: The problem here is that Croatia really should have processed the visa application and the Italian consulate should reject it with instructions to go back to the Croatian consulate.  Whether the applicant here claims "business" or "tourism" as the primary purpose, there is no lie, only well justified confusion.

Comment: Indeed, Croatia should have processed the application, but I don't agree with your point, changing the visa purpose from business to tourism; is not confusion it's omitting information about the stay, and it is 100% deception @phoog

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed the phrase "not mention about the conference in Croatia."  That definitely _is_ misrepresentation.